Как запретить пользователю настраивать политику свойства
Если нажать правую кнопку мыши на свойстве, получим контекстное меню в котором есть пункт "Настройка политики свойства"
Как этот пункт скрыть для части пользователей?


Пункт меню Настройка политики безопасности является обычным действием, доступ к которому также регулируется через политику безопасности. Все такие действия входят в одну группу свойств : Свойства политики безопасности.
Например, чтобы убрать у всех пользователей, кроме администраторов, этот пункт меню нужно :

Зайти в форму Администрирование / Система / Доступ / Политика безопасности и для роли По умолчанию поставить Запретить на просмотр свойств узла дерева Свойства политики безопасности :

В той же самой форме для роли Администратор выставить для того же самого узла дерева значение Разрешить

У пользователя может быть одновременно выбрано несколько ролей, но роль По умолчанию включена всегда. Кроме того, Разрешить всегда приоритетнее Запретить. Таким образом, у всех пользователей, у которых есть роль Администратор пункт будет доступен. Для всех остальных пункт не будет показываться.
